# Lync saves conversation multiple times

Tags: microsoft-outlook, instant-messaging, lync

I am using the Lync feature that saves conversations in the "Conversation History" folder in Outlook. During the time that a conversation is open, it gets saved several times, each saved conversation longer than the previous one.

It's fine that the conversation is saved multiple times and not just when it ends, but you end up with multiple copies of it. Is it possible to only save the conversation when it is closed?

Versions: Outlook 2007, Lync 2010

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Outlook's `Cleanup Folders & Subfolders` functionality doesn't work on the Lync / Skype for Business Conversation History folder because the conversations aren't included in the same "thread".

I used the following program to help me do the cleanup. It sure would be nice if it was built into Outlook's `Cleanup Folders` logic.

http://www.craig-tolley.co.uk/mini-projects/microsoft-lync-conversation-cleanup/

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.

In Outlook 2013, use the Quick Access Toolbar to add command called `Clean Up Folders & Subfolders`.

This will keep only the log you want and delete the partials.

To add the option to the Quick Access Toolbar, click on the arrow pointing down in the Title Bar. Then add the action to your toolbar.

[image]

You should see it in the toolbar after you add it. Click on it any time you want to clean up your Lync conversations.

[image]

Comment: Is this Outlook or Lync? I can't find it in either program

Comment: I have outlook 2013. I guess your version doesn't have this nice feature.